# Authorize.net DPM relay response immediate timeout

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, tomcat7, ssl-certificate, authorize.net

I am hosting my website on Amazon Web Services, EC2 Linux.  My app is running on a Tomcat7 Server.  I am handling payment processing using Authorize.net's DPM framework.

I recently had to upgrade from a t1.micro EC2 instance to a t2.micro EC2 instance.  Since the migration, I get an immediate timeout error, and I can't figure out the culprit.

Things I have tried:

- Ensured that all ports (80, 8080, 443, 8443) are accessible
- Confirmed that the ciphers specified in my server.xml file are not the issue (fails whether or not I specify explicit ciphers, didn't do so on t1.micro instance)
- Increased the TTL on the DNS Servers where my domain is registered from 60 to 3600
- Redirected the relay response to another web address (cloned server running the same app)
- changed my authorize.net mode to 'Test' from 'Live'

None of this appears to be working.  The only piece of data I have to go on is the fact that the timeout happens immediately, so I don't think a response is being sent to ANY server.  Is there a way to verify this?

My SSL Certificate (verified by CA) is SHA256 rather than SHA1, but it was working fine on the t1.micro instance.

Comment: Have you tried using an HTTP connection instead of HTTPS?  This would help isolate if you have the correct target configured.  Also, your relay response URL must be on a standard port 80 or 443.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried both http and https, on multiple servers, and they are all running on standard ports (80 and 443).  I have port-forwarding using itables from 80 to 8080 and from 443 to 8443

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your relay response POST url completely outside your network?  Remember that Authorize.Net is attempting to POST to your page, and if it can't connect, is presented with a login or error message, it will fail.

Comment: Yes, the response URL is public, and I can access it directly via the web.  The response is actually a Java Servlet which takes the results and redirects to either a receipt page or an error page.  

However, neither is happening and I'm not convinced that ANY responses are actually coming in.  I've tried using multiple response URLs, including one in a debugging environment which should immdiately triggger a breakpoint

Comment: I suggest opening a developer support request at http://developer.authorize.net/support and include the relay response URL for Authorize.Net to check.